# Enabling Windows Init System Logs

Tags: windows-10, boot, init

In Linux, if `quiet=n` kernel parameter or softwares like plymouth is not used, the used init system (systemd, openrc, runit etc...) prints logs like [this](https://linuxgazette.net/156/misc/prestia/runlevel3.png) to the screen when booting. These logs includes service starts, fstab mounts and maybe more. How can I make Windows print logs instead of showing [that logo](http://mytechquest.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/Windows-8-RTM-Boot-Screen-for-Windows-7-01.jpg) while booting if it is possible?

(I am currently running Windows 10 build 19042.985.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see Windows boot log to troubleshooting some problems make the following:

Configure Windows to create a boot log:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `msconfig.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. In **System Configuration** `Boot` tab mark `Boot log` and `OS boot information` checkboxes. Press <kbd>OK</kbd> button.

[image]

When the boot log is enabled (after restarting the Windows) you can enter `notepad %SystemRoot%\ntbtlog.txt` to see the boot log.

Also you can configure Windows to receive verbose startup, shutdown, logon, and logoff status messages. See [Enable verbose status messages by using Registry Editor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/enable-verbose-startup-shutdown-logon-logoff-status-messages) chapter in Microsoft documentation.

To enable verbose status messages by editing the registry do the following steps:

```
1. Click Start > Run.

2. In the Open box, type regedit, and then click OK.

3. Locate and then click the following registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

4. On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.

5. Type verbosestatus, and then press ENTER.

6. Double-click the new key that you created, type 1 in the Value data box, and then click OK.

7. Quit Registry Editor.
```